# How to prove that the union of big theta(g(x)) and small o(g(x)) is not big o(g(x))?

Tags: algorithm

[image: The question]

I cannot find an example of that.
So how to prove?

Comment: Please don't post questions consisting of a single link to an external site. If the external content is gone/changed, your question won't make sense, later.

Comment: Consider functions like: f(n) = n if n is even, 1 if n is odd.

Comment: @fgb That's a nice idea. I have to say that when I got this question as an undergrad, it was emphasized that, implicit in the field of algorithmic orders of growth, only monotonically nondecreasing functions are considered (it's possible to solve this subject to this constraint as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sets are not equal then there must be at least one element in one that is not in the other. We will look for one.

Theta and o are both subsets of O, and so must be their union. This means everything in the LHS must be in the RHS. So if we are to find something that makes these sets different it will be something that is O but neither Theta nor o.

Things that are O but not Theta must not be Omega. That is, they must not be bounded from below as they are from above. That whic is O but not o is eventually smaller for some constant, but not for every constant, c > 0.

An easy win here is a discontinuous function that (a) grows asymptotically slower in one case and (b) grows at the same asymptotic rate in the other. For instance, Theta(n^2) in some cases and Theta(n lg n) in others. It will be O(n^2) but not Theta(n^2) or o(n^2).

We can get an algorithm with this time complexity by selecting - randomly or according to the input size, for instance - between bubble sort and merge sort and calling it counterexample sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. English is not my mother-language so I must read it slowly, but I think I can get your point.